# How to connect Marshall Acton to Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth

So I have a Bluetooth speaker: Marshall Acton. It works well with my cellphone, but not with my Asus UX303UB laptop. Windows 7 is installed, bluetooth connection is made. However please see the image below:

[image]

With which service? Where do I click?

In Device properties I see:

[image]

But in Audio Devices, Acton is not available:

[image]